# Can the installation of a silent system in a grand piano interfere with its performance?

Tags: piano, electronics

I am thinking of installing a silent sytem on my piano. I have read and talked with some people about it.

Some people have warned me that the installation of such a system can interfere with the weight of the keys, making it harder to play soft.

Can the installation of a silent system interfere with current performance?
Does it make a difference if the silent system comes from factory or not?

Comment: I've never played on one of these but looking at the technology it seems likely that the feel of the piano would change. Ideally you would be able to find a showroom near you where there is a modified demo piano and you can see for yourself. If you have a product in mind I would reach out to their sales or support and ask where you can try it out.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I don't understand because the system is optical. It doenst interfere with the mechanics, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Your mileage may vary, of course, but for what it's worth, here are my impressions:

We have a couple of Yamaha silent pianos at our home (ordinary stringed pianos with a MIDI interface: one grand and one upright), as well as a digital keyboard with an ordinary piano action.  It might be a *little* harder to play soft, but the difference is pretty small, as far as I can tell, compared to the difference between different piano brands.

However, they were installed before we bought them, so my comparison is with the same model without the silent system (at the same store), but not the same actual piano.

Comment: Is the silent base on optical sensors?